# How to change Youtube video quality on Edge in mobile version?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, microsoft-edge

I don't see any option to change video quality. It's frustrating when you are on a phablet and the video quality is poor.

Comment: On the top right corner you can open the Youtube menu and select to load the desktop version. Seems to be the only option at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube mobile version doesn't allow to change video quality, It selects based on internet speed. If you want to set video quality use 3rd party YouTube apps like tubecast, mytube, client for youtube..